# Prepared Statement with collection in IN clause in Datastax Cassandra CQL driver

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver

I am trying to run the following query

```
SELECT edge_id, b_id FROM booking_by_edge WHERE edge_id IN ?
```

I bind Java list of Long's as a parameter and I get an exception

```
SyntaxError: line 0:-1 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting ')' (ResultSetFuture.java:242)
```

If I try to use (?) it expects single Long item to be bound, but I need a collection

Is there an error in my syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got response on Datastax bugzilla, it is currently not supported, but planned

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4210

Update: Supported in Cassandra 2.0.1

Comment: Could you tell me if it is solved now? I could not quite get the idea from the links.

Answer (score 23):

Tested in Cassandra 2.1.3, the following code snippet works:

```
PreparedStatement prepared = session.prepare("SELECT edge_id, b_id FROM booking_by_edge WHERE edge_id IN ?;");
List<Long> edgeIds = Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L);
session.execute(prepared.bind(edgeIds));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to find in the documentation but it is described in the [tuples section of the manual](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.3/manual/tuples/).

If you want to use named parameters you should use the setList() method.

```
BoundStatement bs = session.prepare("select col from table where col in :values").bind();
bs.setList("values", Arrays.asList(v1, v2, v3));
```