# use datastax java driver to bind data for where in clause

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I know somebody has ask this question (http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/java-driver-cql-3-bound-statements-in-clause#post-13114, [Prepared Statement with collection in IN clause in Datastax Cassandra CQL driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918853/prepared-statement-with-collection-in-in-clause-in-datastax-cassandra-cql-driver))

However, I still do not know how to bind data.
for example, my preparedStatement is

```
select * from cf where key in (?)
```

What I want is bind data and the cql is looks like

```
select * from cf where key in ('key1', 'key2')
```

Now I have a boundStatement.

when I use boundStatment.bind() api. I try to bind ? with a List or a Array, however , it says:

> Column value is of type varchar, cannot set to a list

Ok,  I set a string and use boundStatement.bind like this:

```
boundStatement.bind("'key1','key2'");
```

There is no exception, but the resultSet is empty. Why?  I think because the driver parse it as

```
select * from cf where key in (''key1', 'key2'')
```

(notice a redundant quote because it thinks all the "'key1',and 'key2'" is a string).

So, I know datastax has support in clause. but I can not find some examples ..

Can any help me? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT * FROM cf WHERE key IN ?
```

That will allow you to bind a List for the query parameter.