# How to bind IN-clause values in a CQL 3 prepared statement?

Tags: java, data-binding, cassandra, cql, cql3

I have a table that is roughly like

```
create table mytable (
   id uuid,
   something text,
   primary key (id)
);
```

I'm trying to create a prepared statement that has a bound in-clause:

```
PreparedStatement ps = session.prepare("select * from mytable where id IN (?)");
...
UUID[] ids = { uuid1, uuid2, uuid3} ;
```

No matter how I express the ids to bind, the java driver rejects them.

`ps.bind( /*as array*/)`:  driver complains statement has only one value, 2 supplied

`ps.bind( /*as comma separated string list of uuids*/)`:  driver complains it wants UUID.class objects, not strings

`ps.bind( /*as list object*/)`: driver complains it wants UUID.class objs, not a List.class object

I really hope the driver isn't expecting as many ? place holders as there are values in the in-list, because that means you'd have to reprepare the statement every time you wanted to execute it, which the Datastax docs says not to do!

I looked at the `com.datastax.driver.core.BoundStatement.bind()` method and there is no indication that anything else would work - no magic wrappers or anything.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918853/prepared-statement-with-collection-in-in-clause-in-datastax-cassandra-cql-driver.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The correct syntax is `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN ?` (without parens around the `?`).  This will allow you to pass a list of UUIDs to bind to that single query parameter.

Comment: How can we bind when we have query like SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN ? AND col2 IN ?