# Query builder in clause to prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I want to change following query to prepared statement :

```
QueryBuilder.select().column(id).from(studentTable).where(QueryBuilder.in(id,List)).
```

I know noramlly this query can be written as :

```
select id from studentTable where id = ?
```

How the same can be achieved by `querybuilder` ?

Comment: QueryBuilder is from which library?

Comment: from com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.QueryBuilder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PreparedStatement IN clause alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918853/prepared-statement-with-collection-in-in-clause-in-datastax-cassandra-cql-driver

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this with `QueryBuilder` you need to call the `bindMarker()`, or `bindMarker("name")`... See corresponding [Javadocs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.5/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/QueryBuilder.html#bindMarker--) (example is from it):

```
Insert i = QueryBuilder.insertInto("test").value("k", 0)
                       .value("c", QueryBuilder.bindMarker());
PreparedStatement p = session.prepare(i.toString());
```